# Updating a column name of a same table which has a parent child relationship using mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I searched a lot of doing a task but found no appropriate solution.

Basically the scenario is. I have a user_comment table in which there are 5 column(id,parent_id,user_comments,is_deleted,modified_datetime). There is a parent child relationship like 1->2,1->3,2->4,2->5,5->7 etc. 
Now i am sending the id from the front end and i want to update the column is_deleted to 1 and modified_datetime on all the records on
this id as well as the all the children and children's of children.

I am trying to doing this by using a recursive procedure. Below is the code of my procedure

```
     CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `user_comments`(
     IN mode varchar(45),
     IN comment_id int,
     )
     BEGIN

     DECLARE p_id INT DEFAULT NULL ;

     if(mode = 'delete')
     then
     update user_comment set is_deleted = 1, modified_datetime = now() 
      where id = comment_id ;

     select id from user_comment where parent_id = comment_id into p_id ;

     if p_id is not null
     then 
     SET @@GLOBAL.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
     SET @@session.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255; 
    call user_comments('delete', p_id);
    end if;
    end if;
    END
```

By using this procedure it give me an error of more than one row.
If i return the select query without giving it to variable then shows me the the appropriate results on the select query but i have to call this procedure recursively based on getting the ids of the select query.

I need help i have already passed 2 days into this.

I used cursor also. Below is the code of cursor

```
   CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `user_comments`(
   IN mode varchar(45),
   IN comment_id int,
   )
   BEGIN
   DECLARE p_emp int;
   DECLARE noMoreRow INT;
   DECLARE cur_emp CURSOR FOR  select id from user_comment where parent_id = comment_id ;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET noMoreRow = 0;


   if(mode = 'delete')
   then



   OPEN cur_emp;
     LOOPROWS: LOOP

      IF noMoreRow = 0 THEN
      update user_comment set is_deleted = 1, modified_datetime = now() where id = comment_id 
        CLOSE cur_emp;
        LEAVE LOOPROWS;
    END IF;
    FETCH cur_emp INTO p_emp;
    update user_comment set is_deleted = 1, modified_datetime = now() where id = p_emp ;
    SET @@GLOBAL.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
    SET @@session.max_sp_recursion_depth = 255; 
    call user_comments('delete', p_emp);

    END LOOP;
   end if;
 END
```

After using cursor i am getting a thread error.i don't know how can overcome this problem!!!

Comment: Pls share the exact error message!

Comment: Error Code: 1436. Thread stack overrun:  71628 bytes used of a 196608 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack. 0.156 sec
This error i am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql's documentation on [select ... into varlist](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) clearly says:

> The selected values are assigned to the variables. The number of
>   variables must match the number of columns. The query should return a
>   single row. If the query returns no rows, a warning with error code
>   1329 occurs (No data), and the variable values remain unchanged. If
>   the query returns multiple rows, error 1172 occurs (Result consisted
>   of more than one row). If it is possible that the statement may
>   retrieve multiple rows, you can use LIMIT 1 to limit the result set to
>   a single row.

Since you wrote in the OP that a comment can be parent of many comments, using simple variables cannot be a solution. You should use a [CURSOR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html) instead, that can store an entire resultset.

You loop through the records within the cursos as shown in the sample code in the above link and call `user_comments()` in a recursive way.

UPDATE

If your receive

> Error Code: 1436. Thread stack overrun

error, then you can do 2 things:

1. Increase the `thread_stack` setting in the config file and restart mysql server.
2. You can try to simplify your code to use less recursions and therefore less stack space. For example, when you fetch all children into the cursor, then rather calling the `user_comments()` recursively for each, you can set all direct children's status within the code and call the function recirsively on grand-childrens only (if any). You can also change your data structure and use [nested set](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) model to approach hierarchical structures.

Nested set model is more complex to understand, it is less resource intensive to traverse, but more resource intensive to maintain.

Comment: Thanks Shadow for reply. I have also use the cursor as you said but in a cursor i have to again call the same procedure for each values. I do the same but i am getting the error of thread. I am updating my question where i am using cursor.

Comment: Hi Shadow i find the file my.ini in wamp server but there is no instance of name thread_stack in this file?

Comment: Hint: all server system variables have default values. If no value is defined for such a variable in the ini file, then the default value is assigned.

Comment: you mean that i have to declare this variable and assign value to this in the my.ini file of mysql?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. But beware of relying just on increasing this setting! If you get a nasty subtree, mysql may run out of stack later again.

Comment: If this happen again then what should i do instead of besides this techniques?

Comment: These are the options I'm aware.

Comment: Will you like to tell me what size should i give to this stack as of my error? Currently i have given 124 k.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help with that. You need to experiment a little bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101905/discussion-between-azhar-ahmad-and-shadow).

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have this luxsury at this moment I cannot really help you beyond this point regarding this setting. I would like to emphasize again: try to rewrite the code to have less recursive calls, otherwise you may bump into this error message later.

Comment: Hi Shadow i resolved this problem.Just changing the IF noMoreRow = 0  condition by putting it after the FETCH cur_emp INTO p_emp;

Thanx alot!!!!